# Can't connect to EC2 Postgresql instance unless I change the default port 5432

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, aws, amazon-ec2

I just created a brand new EC2 instance with a default security group allowing **All Traffic** from **Anywhere**.

My listen_address is set to `*`

I can SSH to it but I can't connect to the pgsql instance running inside it, **UNLESS** I change the port to something other than `port=5432`.

## This Setup Fails:

postgresql.conf:
`port=5432`
`psql -h <public-ip> -p 5432`

**ERROR:**

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out`

## This works:

`port=6000`
`psql -h <public-ip> -p 6000`

I tried this **twice** in two different AWS accounts, same behavior.

no iptables rules are present either, it's a brand new EC2 instance:

```
ubuntu@<public-ip>:~$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This doesn't make sense to me at all.

This is the version of Ubuntu I'm running:

```
ubuntu@<public-ip>:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Postgres version:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.6
```

The weirdest thing it was working yesterday, no changes has been made except that I upgraded to `Yosemite 10.10.3 (14D136`.

EDIT:

I checked with another EC2 instance in the cloud as client, it connect, it seems to be my OSX, again, since I updated to `Yosemite 10.10.3`

EDIT 2:

Not just `psql`, none of my client apps are able to connect.

EDIT 3:

`"host=<public-ip> port=5432 sslmode=disable"` didn't worked neither.

Any tips?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2911209/mac-os-x/yosemite-10103-breaks-some-applications-and-https-sites.html) out.

Comment: @Vérace thanks for the comment, but it doesn't work. I also commented out `ssl = true` in `postgresql.conf`, nothing. got any other tips? I'm getting desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an nmap over the EC2 instance:

```
nmap -Pnv -p 5432 <public-ip>
```

revealed that my ISP is intentionally blocking the port `5432`(third-world country FTW...):

```
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

It was never a problem with EC2 nor Postgresql in first place.

Comment: That was my first thought when it was this specific port. Weird port to block. If you want to properly confirm that it's your ISP, you should use `traceroute` in TCP mode, or a similar TCP traceroute tool.